# Why MATLAB is faster than C++ in creating random numbers?

Tags: c++, performance, matlab

I have been using MATLAB for a while for my projects and I have almost never had an experience in C++.

I needed speed and I heard that C++ can be more efficient and faster than MATLAB. So I tried this:

I created a matrix of random numbers using rand(5000,5000) on MATLAB.

And in C++, I have initialized a 2D vector created 2 for loops each of them looping for 5000 times and each time. MATLAB was 4-5x faster, so I thought it is because matlab executes vectorized codes in parallel, then I written the C++ code using parallel_for. Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <ppl.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace concurrency;
int main();
{
    int a = 5000, b = 5000, j, k;
    vector< vector<int> > vec(a, vector<imt>(b));
    parallel_for(int(0), a, [&](int i) {
        for (j = 0; j <b; j++)
        {
            vec[i][j] = rand();
        }
    });
}
```

So the code above is about 25% faster than MATLAB's `rand(5000,5000)` Yet C++ is using 100% of the CPU while MATLAB is using 30% of CPU.

So I forced MATLAB to use all of the CPU by running 3 instances of MATLAB using `rand(5000,5000)` and divided the time it takes by 3. It made MATLAB twice as fast as C++.

I wonder what am I missing? I know this is a tiny example but I need an answer to be sure to port my code to C++.

Current status:

When I write C++ code without `parallel_for` I get half of the MATLAB's speed with the same CPU usage. Yet people who gave answers say that they are almost the same. I do not understand what I am missing

here is a snapshot of the optimization menu
[image]

Comment: May not be related, just curious: did you try using a 1D vector of size 25000 instead, and then pretend it to be 2D during the execution?

Comment: Don't use `vector` here, just create a 2D array of ints. The `[]` operator for vector is not equivalent to the classic `[]` operator, it takes more time to do the job (e.g. check size).

Comment: @Bentoy13 vector `operator[]` does not check size,  you are thinking of `at()`.

Comment: *I need an answer to be sure to port my code to C++*  Stop ! Don't.  Most of Matlab's core computational routines are already written in C++ (or another compiled language) and will out-perform anything you are likely to write yourself.  Many of them are already multi-threaded, if you want to write faster C++ you'll have to do that too. There are many questions and answers here on SO relating to the (generally) useless pursuit of writing faster code than Matlab.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Oh, thanks, I was inverting these ones. Sorry.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark But the guy in the post below says that he can achieve 10x to 100x improvement when porting from MATLAB to C++
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513071/performance-tradeoff-when-is-matlab-better-slower-than-c-c

Comment: @Bentoy13 I did what you said, and the speed was the same with the vector one. And I had to do a workaround because it gives me stackoverflow when I 5000x5000 array of ints instead of vector.

Comment: He says *I have been using Matlab and C++ for about 10 years*  while you admit *I have almost never had an experience in C++.*  That's part of my argument -- it might take you (or me) 10 years with C++ to be able to write faster code for the core computational routines that Matlab provides.  But it's up to you.

Comment: @user2096605 I never say create a _static_ array, `new[]` is way more suitable here. Believe HighPerformanceMark: you shouldn't try to optimize primitive functions of Matlab. Some Matlab code can be faster if rewritten in C++, especially if your write some poorly Matlab code. Start optimizing your matlab code, you can gain speed using their primitive. And if you want best speed, Matlab has a compiler + parallel toolbox (not cheap).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I understand now. But I still think it is beneficial for me to try and see how fast I can get. Also I believe what I ask here is one of the extreme examples because I know such a core Matlab function `rand` should be as efficient as it can be. So learning the optimizations should help me for the rest of the code that are not as efficient in Matlab.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: @Bentoy13 I will do it using arrays.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I am looking into it

Comment: How does c++ handle the seeds in a parallel for? There is a good chance that the code above generates repeated numbers because all threads fork with the same seed set.

Comment: Out of interest, what were the timing results and how did you measure?

Comment: @ChrisDrew I did measure MATLAB using tic toc just like in the first answer I did 100 loops. it took me 50 seconds. In the case of C++ I didn't know the way to do it in like the answer so again I did a 100 loop. I built the code as an executable and measured it manually (using a chronometer) it again took around 45-50 seconds. only thing different was C++ was using all the CPU ( I was doing in parallel) yet matlab was using 30ish % (which is the 100% of 1 thread)

Comment: I did some years ago an Inpaint algorithm in Matlab, after porting it to C++ the gain factor was around 100x... so yes... maybe you have to consider some things. First of all, matlab uses a memory pool, so it is not fair to use "new" here, do it on the stack. Are you compiling with optimizations on?, are you enabling vectorization? btw rand() implementation on Matlab is WAY better than the rand() implementation on you compiler. Another point you are not considering is cache friendly algorithms or prefetching positions to avoid a cache miss..

Comment: (1) rand() sucks. (2) I'd assume the C `rand()` takes a lock on the global RNG state, which kills your parallelism. Give every thread it's own random_device. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217791/random-numbers-in-c0x

Comment: The two random number generators use completely different algorithms with different outputs and statistics. Comparing these is pointless. But you should still be able to easily write a Mersenne twister code in C/C++ that outperforms Matlab's `rand` by a factor of two or three times (I've done it myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call rand(5000,5000) in Matlab, Matlab executes the command by calling Intel MKL library, which is a highly optimized library written in C/C++ with lots of hand-coded assembly.

MKL should be faster than any straightforward C++ implementation, but there is an overhead for Matlab to call external library. The net result is that, for random number generation in smaller sizes (less than 1K for instance), plain C/C++ implementation will be faster, but for larger sizes, Matlab will benefit from super optimized MKL.

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe no answer, but a litle hint. 
The comparison might be a bit unfair due to the usage of `vectors`.

Here is a comparison I've written. Both take up roughly 100% of one of the  four threads available. In both cases I create `5000x5000` random numbers and do this 100 times for timing

**Matlab**

```
function stackoverflow

tic
for i=1:100
    A =rand(5000);
end
toc
```

Runtime: ~27.9 sec

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


int main(){

    int N = 5000;
    double ** A = new double*[N];
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
        A[i] = new double[N];


    srand(time(NULL));

    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int k=0;k<100;k++){
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
                A[i][j] = rand();
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "T="<< (clock()-start)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)<< "ms " << endl;

}
```

Runtime: ~28.7 sec

So both examples run almost equally fast.

Comment: I just used the same comments with no change. Matlab takes 38 seconds yet C++ takes 80ish to complete. What am I missing? I am using visual C++ as my IDE.

Comment: I simply use `g++ filename.c` on a linux machine.

Comment: @ChrisDrew yes I am using in release mode and running manually the exe file

Comment: The two random number generators are completely different algorithms with different outputs and statistics. Matlab's Mersenne twister-based `rand` produces variates on (0,1). C++'s linear-congruential generator-based `rand` produces variates on [0,`RAND_MAX`]. Comparing these is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at @sonystarmap's answer, I added a few types of containers: `double*`, `vector<double>` and `vector<vector<double> >`. I also added tests where the "pointer-containers" are memset, since `vector` initialises all memory.

The C++ code was compiled with these optimization flag: `-O3 -march=native`

The results:

Matlab: Elapsed time is 28.457788 seconds.

C++:

T=23844.2ms

T=25161.5ms

T=25154ms

T=24197.3ms

T=24235.2ms

T=24166.1ms

I can essentially not find the large gain you mention.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int main(){

    const int N = 5000;

    {
        vector<double> A(N*N);

        srand(0);

        clock_t start = clock();
        for (int k=0;k<100;k++){
            for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
                    A[i*N+j] = rand();
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "T="<< (clock()-start)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)<< "ms " << endl;
    }

    {
        vector<vector<double> > A(N);
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
            A[i] = vector<double>(N);

        srand(0);

        clock_t start = clock();
        for (int k=0;k<100;k++){
            for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
                    A[i][j] = rand();
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "T="<< (clock()-start)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)<< "ms " << endl;
    }

    {
        double ** A = new double*[N];
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
            A[i] = new double[N];

        srand(0);

        clock_t start = clock();
        for (int k=0;k<100;k++){
            for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
                    A[i][j] = rand();
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "T="<< (clock()-start)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)<< "ms " << endl;
    }

    {
        double ** A = new double*[N];
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
            A[i] = new double[N];
            memset(A[i], 0, sizeof(double) * N);
        }

        srand(0);

        clock_t start = clock();
        for (int k=0;k<100;k++){
            for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
                    A[i][j] = rand();
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "T="<< (clock()-start)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)<< "ms " << endl;
    }

    {
        double * A = new double[N * N];

        srand(0);

        clock_t start = clock();
        for (int k=0;k<100;k++){
            for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
                    A[i*N + j] = rand();
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "T="<< (clock()-start)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)<< "ms " << endl;
    }

    {
        double * A = new double[N * N];
        memset(A, 0, sizeof(double) * N * N);

        srand(0);

        clock_t start = clock();
        for (int k=0;k<100;k++){
            for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
                    A[i*N + j] = rand();
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "T="<< (clock()-start)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)<< "ms " << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: here is the problem:
I have tried both yours and sonystarmap's solution. I directly copied it to my visual studio. Built it. ran the executable. My C++ result came as 83000ms while Matlab result is 38 seconds (38000 ms)

I do not see why?

Comment: Could you provide your project setup? I'm starting to think you are compiling on debug mode without any optimization.

Comment: here is the photo of the screen where I built the code. I copied your code changed to release from debug. Built it. went to the folder where .exe exists. ran it. that's all I did and I do not know what else to do. You said something about compiling with optimizations on but I do not know how to do it.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hoxffuo3yeuabwe/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: I don't know enough about VS, we need the arguments for the compiler, maybe this is under Project properties or somethign?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
  const int N = 5000;
  std::vector<int> A(N*N);
  srand(0);
  clock_t start = clock();
  for(int k = 0; k < 100; ++k){
    for(int i = 0; i < N * N; ++i) {
        A[i] = rand();
    }
  }
  std::cout << (clock()-start)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000) << "ms" << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Went from 25-27 seconds on my workstation without any optimization flag on the compiler to 21 seconds with

> -O3 -g -Wall -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=5 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -march=native -mtune=native -ffast-math