# C++ is way slower than MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to generate 5000 by 5000 random number matrix. Here is what I do with MATLAB:

```
for i = 1:100
    rand(5000)
end
```

And here is what I do in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


int main(){

    int N = 5000;
    double ** A = new double*[N];
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
        A[i] = new double[N];


    srand(time(NULL));

    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int k=0;k<100;k++){
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
                A[i][j] = rand();
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "T="<< (clock()-start)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)<< "ms " << endl;

}
```

MATLAB takes around 38 seconds while C++ takes around 90 seconds.
In another question, people executed the same code and got same speeds for both C++ and MATLAB.

I am using visual C++ with the following optimizations
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXP8i.png]

I would like to learn what I am missing here? Thank you for all the help.

EDIT: Here is the key thing though...
[Why MATLAB is faster than C++ in creating random numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692856/why-matlab-is-faster-than-c-in-creating-random-numbers)

In this question, people gave me answers where their C++ speeds are same as MATLAB. When I use the same code I get way worse speeds and I am trying to understand why.

Comment: These aren't equivalent.  In the C++ case, you have a non-contiguous array, and each call to `rand` requires a subsequent conversion to `double`.  At least try running with a contiguous array (i.e. `double *A = new double[5000*5000]`).

Comment: Also it should read `CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000.0`. `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is defined as `(long)1000` on VS2015 but better stay on the safe side in case any other compiler/environment use different values.

Comment: Did you compile the c++ with optimizations switched on?

Comment: This comparison is _completely_ meaningless. You know nothing about the differences between the `rand()` implementations, you have a gazillion dynamic allocations, you have next to no memory locality... Stop making such comparisons. If you're writing Matlab write Matlab. If you're writing C++ write C++. Then optimise your final product as/when/if required. Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Actually, I'm no longer sure about locality.  It appears that the OP's code is iterating in a cache-friendly order, and the dimensions are large enough such that the overhead due to non-contiguousness of successive rows should be negligible.  I suspect the bulk of the difference is either due to Matlab secretly using multiple threads, or due to significant differences in how rand operates.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well my question is, why in the following link people are getting same speeds on both C++ and MATLAB using the same code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692856/why-matlab-is-faster-than-c-in-creating-random-numbers

Comment: @radres: Wait, why do you have two essentially identical questions?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth In one of them I thought it was a problem about C++ and MATLAB. But when I see the answers I realized that I, personally, cannot reach the speeds the other people reach so I created another one.

Comment: Are you running the program without the debugger attached? Regardless of optimization.

Comment: @banex Yes I am compiling in release mod

Comment: @radres I'm not talking about compilation. Are you running the program through Debug --> Start Without Debugging?

Comment: @Banex Yes, I was building it in release mode and running it. But now that you said it, I tried your way and I still get the slow timing (1/3 speed of matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test is flawed, as others have noted, and does not even address the statement made by the title.  You are comparing an inbuilt Matlab function to C++, not Matlab code itself, which in fact executes 100x more slowly than C++.  Matlab is just a wrapper around the BLAS/LAPACK libraries in C/Fortran so one would expect a Matlab script, and a competently written C++ to be approximately equivalent, and indeed they are: This code in Matlab 2007b

```
tic; A = rand(5000); toc
```

executes in 810ms on my machine and this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>

#define N 5000
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    clock_t start = clock();

    int num_rows = N,
        num_cols = N;
    double * A = new double[N*N];
    for (int i=0; i<N*N; ++i)
        A[i] = rand();

    std::cout << "T="<< (clock()-start)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)<< "ms " << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

executes in 830ms.  A slight advantage for Matlab's in-house RNG over `rand()` is not too surprising. Note also the single indexing.  *This is how Matlab does it*, internally.  It then uses a clever indexing system (developed by others) to give you a matrix-like interface to the data.

Comment: same codes executes in 830 ms (c++) and the matlab one executes in 343 ms. I am trying to understand this big difference

Comment: @radres Are you using a more recent version of Matlab?  I think more recent RNGs preserve more state between calls and are able to achieve greater efficiency.  In this case the right C++ equivalent wouldn't be `rand()` but something from [std::random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)

Comment: yes, mine is R2014b. Maybe that is the reason it is faster.

Answer (score 3):

In your C++ code, you are doing 5000 allocations of double[5000] on the heap. You would probably get much better speed if you did a single allocation of a double[25000000], and then do your own arithmetic to convert your 2 indices to a single one.

Comment: but here is the problem, people are using the same code and getting the same speeds on both c++ and matlab. I dont understand that.

Comment: @radres Why don't you ask those people?

Answer (score 0):

I believe MATLAB utilize multiple cpu cores on your machine. Have you try to write a multi-threaded version and measure the difference?

Also, the quality of (pseudo) random would also make slightly difference (but not that much).

Comment: I have tried using parallel_for it is of course way faster yet when I run either matlab or c++ they are both using only 1 core of the CPU. And again, there are other people using the same code and getting faster C++ speeds compared to mine. I do not understand what im doing wrong

Comment: Like other suggested, your memory layout is not contiguous, you also waste an indirect de-referencing on each double. That can significantly hurts performance and cause cache pollutions.

Comment: Matlab does not use multiple cores here. There is only one state for the random number stream which can be manipulated by only one thread at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience,

- First check that you execute your C++ code in release mode instead of in Debug mode. (Although I see in the picture you are in release mode)
- Consider MPI parallelization.
- Bear in mind that MATLAB is highly optimized and compiled with the Intel compiler which produces faster executables. You can also try more advanced compilers if you can afford them.
- Last you can make a loop aggregation by using a function to generate combinations of i, j in a single loop. (In python this is a common practice given by the function `product` from the `itertools` library, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279051/how-can-i-create-cartesian-product-of-vector-of-vectors))

I hope it helps.