# Formula used for function rand() in c++

Tags: c++, random

I want to know what is the formula used for generating random numbers using the `rand()` function in C++. At first I though it would return random numbers every time, but it does not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    srand(9865);
    cout << rand() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here I thought that, maybe because of given seed number and that unknown formula, it will be showing same number.

But, when i removed "srand(9865);" and execute several times it is showing only "41" as output. Please explain me what is all going on here.

Comment: Search for the glibc code to know how is it actually implemented and the rand maual page on how rand and srand interact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand

"If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is automatically seeded with a value of 1. ", and "..These sequences are repeatable by calling srand() with the same seed value. "

Comment: i visited the page u given above , and seen this  :int myrand(void) {
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return((unsigned)(next/65536) % 32768);
},    

void mysrand(unsigned seed) {
    next = seed;
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           is this the formula used for generating random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to seed your random function with a non static seed every time. One simple but not so accurate solution is to seed it with the clock:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << rand() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The library specifications don't dictate the formula for the random number generator (it is up to the implementation). The only things specified are that things can be controlled via [`srand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/) for consistent pseudo-random generation:

> In order to generate random-like numbers, srand is usually initialized to some distinctive runtime value, like the value returned by function time (declared in header <ctime>). This is distinctive enough for most trivial randomization needs.

So:

1. If you initialize `srand` with a given seed, the following `rand` calls will be consistent across runs.
2. If you initialize `srand` with a time-based seed, the following `rand` calls will almost surely be different across runs.
3. If you do not initialize `srand`, the following calls to `rand` will use the default initial seed.

---

Note that in contemporary C++, you should avoid using these ancient functions. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217791/random-numbers-in-c0x).